reentrance in ERC20 token transfer
Since ERC20 token transfer is prone to reentrance attack because they do not invoke any function in external contract. is it okay to update the state after external call??. since its impossible for attacker to exploit the contract.CODE =
function emergencyWithdraw(uint256 _pid) public {
        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];
        UserInfo storage user = userInfo[_pid][msg.sender];
        pool.lpToken.safeTransfer(address(msg.sender), user.amount);
        emit EmergencyWithdraw(msg.sender, _pid, user.amount);
        user.amount = 0;
        user.rewardDebt = 0;
    }


The emergencyWithdraw function is vulnerable to reentrancy attacks because it makes an external call (safeTransfer) before updating the state. This violates the checks-effects-interactions security principle.
To fix this:

Apply the checks-effects-interactions pattern:
- Update the user's state (user.amount and user.rewardDebt) before calling safeTransfer.


sorry for late text. yes i know it  vulnerable to reentrancy with design logic, but there no way to exploit it since "safeTransfer" used to send token out is prone to reentrance.

@OliviaNicole,
safeTransfer is a secure method for transferring tokens and is less likely to introduce reentrancy on its own, it does not inherently prevent reentrancy if the token contract itself is malicious or improperly implemented. To fully mitigate the risk, it's best practice to update the user's state before making any external calls.
